# html emaim image outlook

Tags: html, outlook, html-email

Outlook just displays a small box with a red X, when I test my HTML email. All the images looks like this:

```
<td align="center">
    <a href="http://www.example.com"><img src="https://c1.staticflickr.com/6/5516/29542162544_71ebdbac9f_z.jpg" alt="second-typo" style="display: block;" width="100%"/></a>
</td>
```

Is there any solution, to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Outlook does not download remote images unless the user explicitly allows Outlook to do that for that particular email.

Embed the images as an attachments and refer to it through the cid (`<img src=cid:xyz>`). Note that Outlook does not support embedding binary data into the img tag.